# How to get soap Body

Tags: java, http, soap, envelope

here i am getting null for every response while extracting the body or envelop etc please suggest why
String  ret="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\r\n" + 
                "    \r\n" + 
                "    \r\n" + 
                "        https://singpostuat2-staging.oss.neopost-id.com/modules/oss/api/ship/sz_Client\">\r\n" + 
                "            \r\n" + 
                "                \r\n" + 
                "                    `STATUS_SUCCESS`\r\n" + 
                "                    Transaction has been successfully completed!!\r\n" + 
                "                    \r\n" + 
                "                        \r\n" + 
                "                        \r\n" + 
                "                        EQ026174556SG\r\n" + 
                "                        EQ026174556SG\r\n" + 
                "                        \r\n" + 
                "                        \r\n" + 
                "                    \r\n" + 
                "                \r\n" + 
                "            \r\n" + 
                "        \r\n" + 
                "    \r\n" + 
                "";

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
        MessageFactory factory = null;
        try {
            factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();

        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = null;

            byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(soapreq.getBytes());



            SOAPMessage resp=  factory.createMessage(new MimeHeaders(), byteArrayInputStream);
        System.out.println(resp.toString());
        Node respon=getFirstElement(resp);
        System.out.println(respon);
        resp.getSOAPBody();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

public static Node getFirstElement(SOAPMessage message) throws SOAPException {
    final NodeList childNodes = message.getSOAPBody().getChildNodes();
    Node firstElement = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++) {
        if (childNodes.item(i) instanceof Element) {
            firstElement = childNodes.item(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    return firstElement;
}
```

Comment: String  soapreq="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n" + 
   "<soapenv:Envelope\r\n" + 
   "        xml

Comment: in this method i am providing sample soapxml but getting null for envelop body please help its urgent

Comment: Please update your question with value of `soapreq` and format the code you have provided

Comment: Updated the question please check